# Lazy Loading Router Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, lazy-loading, angular-routing

Got some troubles with Lazy Loading. All urls shows me empty pages.

Structure:

```
- app.module.ts
- modules
   - router.module.ts
- scenes
   - dashboard
      - dashboard.module.ts
      - router.module.ts
```

I have

```
imports: [
    RoutingModule,
]
```

in **app.module.ts**

**routing.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        loadChildren: '../scenes/dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: []
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

Notice that i have '../scenes' because it is in different folders with app.module.ts.

**dashboard.module.ts:**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardRoutingModule } from './routing.module';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        DashboardRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

**routing.module.ts (in dashboard):**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'transactions', loadChildren: './transactions#TransactionsModule' },
        ]
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule],
    declarations: [DashboardComponent]
})
export class DashboardRoutingModule { }
```

Checked html-code and I have empty router-outlet so seems like even dashboard.component wont load.

Also is it possible to make it work with using index.ts files. I mean will it work with this?

```
{ path: 'transactions', loadChildren: './transactions#TransactionsModule' }
```

Transactions is a folder with **index.ts** file that exports all data from module:

```
export * from './transactions.module';
```

**ERROR:**

> GET http://localhost:4200/dashboard/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
>   (Not Found)

**SOLUTION:**

I had component with name **main** and **loadChildren: './main#MainModule'** and name of generated chunk was **main.js** but it already exists by default.

Comment: show your console message. It seems that you need to set empty path (at app routing) redirect to lazy loading dashboard module

Comment: @DanielEduardoDelgadoDiaz i`m trying localhost/dashboard so it must work well. Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code is good. How about your `router-outlet` directives? You mast have one in your app.component.html and one in your dashboard.component.html

> I have a similar example at my github repo. It has a full architecture starter: https://github.com/dedd1993/ngx-admin

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in app.module you also need to import your child modules, like this.

app.module.ts

```
 imports: [
    UserRoutes,
    AppRoutingModule
]
```

UserRoutes:

```
const userRoutesModule: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: UserComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'domanda/edit',
        canDeactivate: [EditDomandaGuard],
        component: EditDomandaComponent,
      },
      {path: 'domanda', component: DomandaComponent},
      {path: 'help', component: HelpComponent},
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(userRoutesModule)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class UserRoutes {
}
```

AppRoutingModule:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      {
        path: '',
        component: UserComponent,
        children: [
          {path: 'domanda/edit', component: EditDomandaComponent},
          {path: 'domanda', component: DomandaComponent},
          {path: 'help', component: HelpComponent},
        ]
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: GuestComponent,
        children: [
          {path: 'help', component: HelpComponent},
          {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
        ]
      },
      {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent}
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule],
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {
    }
```

So your app.module.ts should become:

```
imports: [
DashboardRoutingModule,
    RoutingModule,
]
```

The code is take from one of my repository on github feel free to see how it's work: https://github.com/RabbitHols/pca/tree/dev/src/frontend/src/app/module/routes